# Find the value of $\tan(a+ib)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

We are not unfamiliar to imaginary angles, so what can be $\tan(a+ib)$

> If$$\tan(a+ib)=x+iy$$then find $$x,y$$

My attempt,

Let $x$ and $z$ be two complex bombers such that,
$$\tan(z)=x$$
$$z=\tan^{-1} (x)$$
$$z=\tan^{-1}(re^{i\theta}).$$
But this doesn't seem to get me anywhere, how do we proceed?

Comment: Yeah, I've never gotten very far with complex bombers either... ;-)

Comment: It's unclear to me whether $x,z$ are kind of planes or Bomberman characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb R$.

If so we have:

$$\tan(a+bi)=\frac{\tan{a}+\tan{bi}}{1-\tan a\tan{bi}}=\frac{\tan{a}+i\frac{e^b-e^{-b}}{e^b+e^{-b}}}{1-i\tan{a}\cdot\frac{e^b-e^{-b}}{e^b+e^{-b}}}=...$$
I hope now it's clear.

We know that $$e^{iz}=\cos{z}+i\sin{z}.$$
For $z=xi$ we obtain:
$$e^{-x}=\cos(xi)+i\sin(xi)$$ and for $z=-xi$ we obtain:
$$e^{x}=\cos(xi)-i\sin(xi).$$

Thus, $$\cos(xi)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2},$$
$$\sin(xi)=\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2i}=i\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$ and from here
$$\tan(xi)=i\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Not that , sorry, i will edit the question

Comment: @neonpokharkar I added something. See now.

Comment: How can you write $$\tan(ai)=i\frac{e^a-e^{-a}}{e^a+e^{-a}}$$

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but i really didn't understand that step

Comment: Are you familiar that $$\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} {2i}$$ and $$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}} 2$$? Letting $x \to ai$ it should be clearer as to how to  reach this form.

Comment: @neonpokharkar I added again.

Answer (score 1):

We get a rather pretty formula in terms of double angles after a fair chunk of work, giving
$$\boxed{\tan(a+ib) = \frac{\sin(2a)+i\sinh(2b)}{\cos(2a) + \cosh(2b)}}$$

The brief gist is just repeated application of the hyperbolic-to-trig identities $\sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)$ and $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$, and numerous hyperbolic and trig sum identities. It is a good idea to try and work through all of the steps, using identities from your favorite internet source.

\begin{align}
\tan(a+ib) &= \frac{\sin(a+ib)}{\cos(a+ib)}
= \frac{\sin(a)\cos(ib) + \sin(ib)\cos(a)}{\cos(a)\cos(ib)-\sin(a)\sin(ib)}\\
&= \frac{\sin(a)\cosh(b) + i\sinh(b)\cos(a)}{\cos(a)\cosh(b) - i\sin(a)\sinh(b)} \cdot \frac{\cos(a)\cosh(b) + i\sin(a)\sinh(b)}{{\cos(a)\cosh(b) + i\sin(a)\sinh(b)}} \\
&= \frac{\sin(a)\cos(a)\left[\cosh^2(b)-\sinh^2(b)\right]+ i\,2 \sinh(b)\cosh(b)\left[\sin^2(a)+\cos^2(a)\right]}{\cos^2(a)\cosh^2(b)+\sin^2(a)\sinh^2(b)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{\sin(2a)}{2} + i\frac{\sinh(2b)}{2}}{\cos^2(a)\cosh^2(b)+\sin^2(a)\sinh^2(b)}\\
&= 2\frac{\sin(2a) + i\sinh(2b)}{\left[1+\cos(2a)\right]\left[1+\cosh(2b)\right]+\left[1-\cos(2a)\right]\left[\cosh(2b)-1\right]}\\
&= \frac{\sin(2a)+i\sinh(2b)}{\cos(2a) + \cosh(2b)}
\end{align}

For a sanity check, on the reals $a+i\cdot0$:
$$\frac{\sin(2a)+i\sinh(2\cdot0)}{\cos(2a)+\cosh(2\cdot0)}
= \frac{\left[2\sin(a)\cos(a)\right] + i(0)}{\left[2\cos^2(a)-1\right] + (1)}
= \frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)} = \tan(a+i\cdot0)$$
For imaginaries $(0)+ib$:
$$\frac{\sin(2\cdot0)+i\sinh(2b)}{\cos(2\cdot 0) + \cosh(2b)}
= \frac{(0) + i\left[2\sinh(b)\cosh(b)\right]}{(1) + \left[2\cosh^2(b)-1\right]}
=\frac{i\sinh(b)}{\cosh(b)}
= \frac{\sin(ib)}{\cos(ib)}
= \tan((0)+ib)$$

Comment: I only used $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and Euler's equation ($e^{i\,x}=\cos x+i\sin x$), but I also ended up with the same result.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I did not know the pretty form beforehand and really had to hammer it out. I only had a suspicion of the general form, so this shows how I "discovered it". Showing it when you know the answer is trivial.

In fact, if you just hand wave a step of algebra, a one line proof:
$$\tan(a+ib)
= \frac{\frac{e^{i(a+ib)}-e^{-i(a+ib)}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{i(a+ib)}+e^{-i(a+ib)}}{2}}
= \frac{ \frac{e^{i2a}-e^{-i2a}}{2i} + i\frac{e^{2b}-e^{-2b}}{2} }
{\frac{e^{i2a}+e^{-i2a}}{2} + i\frac{e^{2b}+e^{-2b}}{2} }
=\frac{\sin(2a)+i\sinh(2b)}{\cos(2a)+\cosh(2b)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the relations between complex circular and hyperbolic functions, mainly
$$\tan iz=i\tanh z.$$
From the addition formula, we obtain
$$\tan(a+ib)=\frac{\tan a+\tan ib}{1-\tan a\tan ib}=\frac{\tan a+i\tanh b}{1-i\tan a\tanh b}$$
If you want a cartesian form of the result, multiplying by the conjugate expression f the denominator, you get 
$$\frac{\tan a(1-\tanh^2b)+i\tanh b(1+\tan^2a)}{1+\tan^2a\tanh^2b}.$$

Comment: Which lead to $$x=\frac{\sin (2 a)}{\cos (2 a)+\cosh (2 b)},y=\frac{\sinh (2 b)}{\cos (2 a)+\cosh (2 b)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

From the complex definitions of the trigonometric functions,

$$\tan z=\frac2{2i}\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}.$$

When you substitute $z=a+ib$,

$$\tan(a+ib)=\frac1i\frac{e^{-b+ia}-e^{b-ia}}{e^{-b+ia}+e^{b-ia}}=-i\frac{e^{-b+ia}-e^{b-ia}}{e^{-b+ia}+e^{b-ia}}\,\frac{e^{-b-ia}-e^{b+ia}}{e^{-b-ia}+e^{b+ia}}.$$

The denominator is now a real function,

$$e^{-2b}+e^{2ia}+e^{-2ia}+e^{2b}=e^{2b}+e^{-2b}+2\cos(2a).$$ (You can also use the hyperbolic functions and write $2\cosh(2b)+2\cos(2a)$.)

The real and imaginary parts of the numerator easily follow.